# Unable to check object values in javascript json prepared from json encoded php array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

Server side code

```
$NATIVE_TEST_TEMPLATE_IDS = array(145);
```

Client side code to assign PHP array into javascript -

```
var nativetestTemplates = "<?php echo json_encode($NATIVE_TEST_TEMPLATE_IDS); ?>"; //PHP array into JSON.
```

But now, the JSON object nativetestTemplates that I have here does not look ready for doing Object instance checks. I need to check if, say, 145 exists in the object nativetestTemplates.

Following are details of console log -

```
nativetestTemplates.length -> 5
```

Also, the individual elements of the array have the following -

```
nativetestTemplates[0] -> [
nativetestTemplates[1] -> 1
nativetestTemplates[2] -> 4
nativetestTemplates[3] -> 5
nativetestTemplates[4] -> ]
```

***So, what did I do wrong and what is the best method to check if an element exists in the object.***

**Update**

After fixing mistake pointed out by Djave, I am still having problem checking if an element exists in the object nativetestTemplates.

Here is my code -

*Case 1*

```
var testAdnetworkId = $("#adnetwork_type").val(); //reading selected dropdown value
console.log("see "+$.inArray(testAdnetworkId, nativetestTemplates)+" and "+nativetestTemplates[testAdnetworkId]);
```

This returns following even when testAdnetworkId has a matching value -

```
see -1 and undefined
```

*Case 2*

But, if I do this -

```
var testAdnetworkId = 145; //hardcoded integer val
```

I get the desired output for $.inArray check -

```
 see 0 and undefined
```

console.dir of testAdnetworkId  in case 1 gives this -

0   "1"

1   "4"

2   "5"

However in case 2, it gives -

0   145

Can, someone please explain the proper way to do object property check in Case 1 (reading value of select dropdown)

Comment: tried parsing it? `var nativetestTemplates = JSON.parse(json_encoded_string);`

Comment: At which step, and how will it benefit? I have now corrected the mistake, as pointed out by Djave.

Answer (score 3):

Don't wrap it in quotes, you are saying

```
var nativetestTemplates = "[145]";
```

you want it to say

```
var nativetestTemplates = [145];
```

So, your code would read:

```
var nativetestTemplates = <?php echo json_encode($NATIVE_TEST_TEMPLATE_IDS); ?>; //PHP array into JSON.
```

The reason that you are getting the weird output (`[`, `1`, `2` etc) is that Javascript is just finding the **character** 0, 1, 2 characters from the start of the **string**, rather than the **item** at the start of the **array**.

**Edit**

Funnily enough its the same issue, you are muddling up your variable types again. Because you are getting the `val()` of (I imagine) an input field, you are looking for a **string** again.

```
console.log(typeof($("#adnetwork_type").val())); // Logs 'string'
```

Don't fret though, you can fix this.

```
var testAdnetworkId = parseInt($("#adnetwork_type").val()); //reading selected dropdown value
```

`parseInt()` is your friend. It tries its best to replace a string or other variable with a number, which is what you want. You will see here http://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/Kjgfh that it works.

More on variable types:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. But I am still having an issue. Please check my question update.

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse json variable in javascript as following:

nativetestTemplates = JSON.parse(nativetestTemplates);

Now nativetestTemplates.length will give you correct result.